# How to retrieve text from a QLineEdit object?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an array of pointers to QLineEdit objects, and I would like to iterate through them and output the text that they hold. It seems like I'm having trouble with pointers..

```
QList<QLineEdit *> boxes = ui->gridLayoutWidget->findChildren<QLineEdit *>();
for(QList<QLineEdit *>::iterator it = boxes.begin(); it != boxes.end(); it++)
{
    qDebug() << **it->text();  //not sure how to make this correct
}
```

I can output the object and name with qDebug, so I know the findChildren() and iterator is set up alright, but I'm not sure how to get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for(QList<QLineEdit *>::iterator it = boxes.begin(); it != boxes.end(); it++)
{
     qDebug() << (*it)->text();  
}
```

It's the same as below code, just save one intermediate pointer:

```
for(QList<QLineEdit *>::iterator it = boxes.begin(); it != boxes.end(); it++)
{
    QlineEdit* p= *it; // dereference iterator, get the stored element.
    qDebug() << p->text();
}
```

`operator->` has higher precedence than `operator*`, see C++ [operator wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)

Comment: That was it. What do the parenthesis add?

Comment: you need dereference iterator first because of c++ operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using iterators? Qt has the nice `foreach` loop which does this stuff for you and simplifies the syntax:

```
QList<QLineEdit *> boxes = ui->gridLayoutWidget->findChildren<QLineEdit *>();

foreach(QLineEdit *box, boxes) {
    qDebug() << box->text();
}
```